# How to calculate most recent (date wise) and MAX of prodcount in power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]In power BI using the in built functionalities , i have achieved how to take out the **most recent production count (MAX)** by the following steps:

```
1. Relative date filtering by 1 day (including today) and Choosing the latest date value in the Viz section
2. Filtering shift to TOP N , TOP 1 by LATEST time
3. Choosing the max value of production count in Viz section
```

I want to create a measure for only showing the production count of the highlight as in the picture

Comment: It will be nice if you give a sample data and expected output. That will buttress your question further

Comment: hi! I have added a sample piece of data , please check and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This measure will do the trick:

[image]

Comment: CALCULATE(MAX(tablename[column_name])) works :)! Thanks

Comment: Yep, sure it works :) This is exactly your sample data and the value is correct.